# Modifying SV func

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to modify `StringVar()` such that the previous data can be remembered

```
class sv(sv):
    def __init__(self):
        self.svm_history = []
        self._name = StringVar()

    def SVM_set(self):
        if self._names:
            if svm_value!=self._name:
                self.svm_history.append(self._name)
                self._name = svm_value

    def SVM_undo(self):    
        return self.svm_history[-2]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: WAT? Your Exception doesn't really relate to your code

Comment: Please add your full error traceback and the code causing the exception to your question!

Comment: It has something to do with Tkinter - I forgot to add. Hold on I'll edit!

Comment: Edited! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you call the `__init__` of the parent type too; and as you are doing that, add the necessary parameters too:

```
class StringV_Memory (StringVar):
    def __init__ (self, master=None, value=None, name=None):
        StringVar.__init__(self, master, value, name)

        # the rest of your code
```

Doing this will make sure that the necessary things will be initialized correctly; and your error should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [the answer by poke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30368529/3714930), you are using the Tkinter StringVar in the wrong way. You are overwriting `self._name` with a StringVar which you shouldn't do because you inherit from StingVar. Then you use that as a variable, without using `.set()` and `.get()`.

I'd recommend you to do it something like the code below, which allows the user to use regular `.set()` and `.get()` methods, and adding the `.undo()` method. Note that undo now doesn't actually change the value, it just returns the last value before the current one.

---

The Class:

```
class StringV_Memory(StringVar):
    def __init__(self, master=None, value=None, name=None):
        StringVar.__init__(self, master, value, name)
        self._tk.globalsetvar(self._name, value)
        self.svm_history = []
        self.svm_value = None 

    def set(self, svm_value):
        try:
            old = self.get()
        except TclError:
            # During Variable.__init__() set() is called but there is nothing to get yet
            # this will yield a TclError which you can catch and initialize the StringVar with an empty string
            self._tk.globalsetvar(self._name, '')
        else:
            if svm_value != old:
                self.svm_history.append(old)
                self._tk.globalsetvar(self._name, svm_value)

    def undo(self):    
        return self.svm_history[-1]
```

Which you can use like:

```
root = Tk()
a = StringV_Memory(root)

a.set('1')
a.set('2')
a.set('3')

print a.get()
print a.undo()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, though, the undo doesn't work right - how would you go about implementing an iterative undo, such that every time you run undo - it resets the value to the previous value? I tried to modify your code and am not having any luck